# Non-Serializable Attributes in LogicalViewMap

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I just stumbled upon some serialization issues in a recent project.
While there are some common mistakes like beans residing in view scope without implementing `Serializable` there are some more sophisticated issues, that I dont have an answer for right now.

1) How to deal with `@ManagedProperty` when the injected instance is not serializable?
In this case a certain service implemented as singleton `Spring` bean is injected. While I could mark the attribute `transient`this would leave the attribute with `null` upon deserialization of the managed bean. Another, rather unesthetic, approach is to omit the attribute und do a lookup when the service is needed (probabyl encapsuled in the `getService()` method).
While there is an approach for `Spring` beans using scoped proxies, I'm unsure how this problem should be solved when `Spring` is not used or another non-Spring bean with longer lived scope than 'Request' is injected.

2) During inspection of the `ViewMap` I noticed that it is sometimes not serializable because of some `Mojarra` built-in classes that are not Serializable by default, e.g.`javax.faces.view.facelets.ConverterHandler`. I don't understand why this was put by `Mojarra` in the `ViewMap` anyway.

3) With observations made in 2): 
Is it necessary for the ViewMap to be Serializable with standard Java serialization methods? From my understanding, everything that ends up in a `HttpSession`needs to be serializable but maybe there is some hidden serialization trick applied by `Mojarra` that I'm not aware of.

4) Deserialization seems never to happen except if `com.sun.faces.serializeServerState` is set.
I put `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException` and `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException`in a `@ViewScoped`bean to see how serialization happens. But interestingly, while `writeObject` 
 is called upon completion of the Lifecycle, `readObject`is never called, except if the `context-param`mentioned above is set. This leads to the question why Objects are beeing serialized when they will never be deserialized.

This observations were made with Mojarra 2.1.6 on Tomcat 7.0.11.

It would be great if someone with more insights coulds shed some light on this.

Thx

Comment: Are you sure you really need session serialization? We have a couple hundreds concurrent users on our production systems where it's disabled and it never seemed like a feature someone would miss.

Comment: @mrembisz You are right, session serialization is not really neccessary. I was playing around to solve some memory consumptions issues when i noticed the behavior described in 4). But I find it very interesting that deserialization of the view map never seems to happen when session serialization is turned off. Why is the view map serialized then?